# octave: can I print the format of a struct?

Tags: octave

I can explore a struct on the command line, like,

```
octave:1> fieldnames(data)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = training
  [2,1] = validation
  [3,1] = test
}
octave:2> fieldnames(data.training)
ans = 
{
  [1,1] = inputs
  [2,1] = targets
}
```

but, is there any way I could dump the entire structure? I'm envisioning some kind of output like,

```
data :: struct
   training :: struct
       inputs :: 256x1000 double
...
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Basic Usage & Examples](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Usage-and-Examples.html) where it says

> Note that when Octave prints the value of a structure that contains other structures, only a few levels are displayed. [...] This prevents long and confusing output from large deeply nested structures. The number of levels to print for nested structures may be set with the function `struct_levels_to_print`, and the function `print_struct_array_contents` may be used to enable printing of the contents of structure arrays.